# creating .txt file from S function

Tags: simulink, s-function

I have an C mex S function which can print output to the .txt file.
This code inside  mdlStart(SimStruct *S) creates datafile.txt file and appends the output.

```
  void** pwork = ssGetPWork(S);
  FILE *datafile;

  datafile = fopen("datafile.txt","a");
  pwork[0] =  datafile;
```

So now I want to dynamically get the filename of .txt file from user through S function mask . so , How can I receive string value of filename from mask inside S function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yo will need to declare the mask parameter

[image]

the, you will need to pass the filename to SFunction parameter

[image]

Last, you will use the parameter inside the sfunction, like this:

```
 mxGetPr(ssGetSFcnParam(S,0));
```

See:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/ssgetsfcnparam.html
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36028-integer-parameters-to-c-mex-s-function

Comment: I think to accept parameter from mask i.e array of char inside s function i need to use int mxGetString(const mxArray *pm, char *str, mwSize strlen); method ...Thanx for the help :)

Comment: I didn't test the solution by myself, so you are probably correct. I just gave you the direction to follow. Let me know if it works. May the force be with you :-)

Comment: i followed your suggested procedure but to get parameter value i used mxGetString ....It's Working .Thanx for the help:)